# Top Left Corner of the display not rendered while using Final Cut Pro 10.0.8

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I noticed this strange problem when when I was using Final Cut Pro. The top left corner of the display does not appear. The same can be seen on the image below.

[image]

I left it for a while and when checked, It seemed to have turned black.

[image]

This has happened over a few times to me in the past only when starting to use FCP.

### Hardware and Software

- MBP 13 inch, Late 2011 - OS X Mavericks 10.9.4
- Final Cut Pro 10.0.8

### Question

1. What was the reason this could have occurred?
2. Is there anyway to solve this without having to "reboot"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Final Cut Pro from 10.0.8 to 10.1.2 has solved this problem.